# Software center will not let me authorize

Tags: 11.10, software-center, authentication

When trying to install a program from the software center it will ask for a password. I enter my password and the authentication window goes away and/or tells me there is a problem and the program never installs. I can't get passed it. Please help! There is no problem, my password is correct.

Comment: Can you post the error message please!

Comment: Yes, the error says "Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again."

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. There is a bug in Ubuntu where you set automatic login. When you change your root user account to automatic login you delete your password and it will no longer work. You must change ownership with `sudo chown -R myusername:myusername /home/myusername`

Thanks to Sergey for the answer!
[Setup auto login and now I do not have root authorization for anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69534/setup-auto-login-and-now-i-do-not-have-root-authorization-for-anything)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the package via terminal? Try running `sudo apt-get install [name of the package]` in a shell.

Comment: Interesting, my password is no longer valid. I did set up my machine for automatic login and now I can't set a password for my account. I guess this eliminated has screwed everything up.

Comment: Try opening a shell and running 'sudo passwd [usrname]'.

Comment: I tried the password recovery method that has been posted by Jorge but I get the "authentication manipulation tool error"

Comment: sudo passwd [username] does not work either.

Comment: You know what is strange is that my password and my keyring are the same. The keyring works fine. Again, I did set up for automatic login with the hopes it would quit asking for the keyring but it didn't, so there really was no point.

Comment: I encountered similar issues too. I think probably you should open a new question, this one is pretty much obsolete.

Comment: Ok, now that I realize I cannot create a new root password. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I wasn't that helpful.