# Setup auto login and now I do not have root authorization for anything

Tags: 11.10, password, root

I am the sole user of my computer so I use my root user name for everything. I am tired of logging in all the time and entering a keyring so I was hoping that creating an automatic login would resolve that. It didn't, so now I have a broken password and I cannot install any programs and I cannot fix my password. Does anybody have any help for this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging in as `root` instead of your normal account is an **Incredibly Bad Idea**. During the normal course of things, the only time Ubuntu asks you for a password is when you install new software or updates - and even that can be configured not to require a password, I believe.

If you can no longer log in because you don't remember the password, you could reboot to the recovery console and change your user's password from there:

```
passwd myusername
```

however, I'm afraid you may've stuffed the permissions up when opening your files as root... you may need to change ownership of your home dir:

```
chown -R myusername:myusername /home/myusername
```