# authentication problem at Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: permissions, root, authentication, gvfs, chown

I get this error when I try to authenticate using Gnome GUI. I have NO authentication problem when I use terminal. It is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/69734) that I need to do

```
sudo chown -R myusername:myusername /home/myusername
```

However this leads to another error

```
chown: cannot access `/home/myusername/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

And this happens even if I run the above command as root. I read in [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/34333) that .gfvs is a FUSE mount point so it can not be manipulated by root. However still have no clue how to fix this.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

That error message doesn't mean the command didn't do its job. It's normal for the GNOME VFS mounts folder `~/.gvfs` to be impervious to manual changes, since it's perpetually locked and in use (what you read on Launchpad is correct). You could try `chown`ing it *without* `sudo` and that *might* succeed, but really that folder is extremely unlikely to be relevant to the problem you're experiencing. The contents of that folder are not likely to be responsible for any problems authenticating to log in or to perform administrative tasks (including in the Software Center).

If this was your only error message, it probably means [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/69734/22949) didn't work for you, and you'll have to seek other possible solutions to your problem in [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69509/software-center-will-not-let-me-authorize).

Comment: Ok mate .gvfs may not be relevant, but it's really strange. After doing chown, I defined myusername in visudo as a root, but still no cure.